# Getting null pointer exception when using getLayoutParams()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, layoutparams

I have a custom ImageView class (I don't think the code in the class matters but I'll include it here anyway incase it is needed):

```
    package com.example.vroy.customcirclebuttontest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CircleButton extends ImageView {`

private  int radius;
private  int x;
private  int y;

public CircleButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    constructorTask();
}

public CircleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    constructorTask();
}

public CircleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    constructorTask();
}

public CircleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    constructorTask();
}


private void constructorTask() {
    x = 300;
    y = 300;
    radius = 100;
}

@Override
public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
    super.setPressed(pressed);
    Log.i("Button Logger","Button Pressed");
}

@Override
protected  void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, GameView.green);
    Log.i("Drawing status", "CircleButton Drawing..." + " " + Integer.toString(this.x) + "," + Integer.toString(this.y));
}

}
```

I declare a instance of this class in my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    testCircleButton = new CircleButton(getApplicationContext());
    makeFullScreen();

   testCircleButton.getLayoutParams().width = 200;
   testCircleButton.getLayoutParams().height = 200;

    RelativeLayout screenLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.screenLayout);
    screenLayout.addView(testCircleButton);

    Log.i("Button Status","Adding Button To Layout");
}
```

However when I do this I get a "null pointer" exception.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your `testCircleButton` is not attached to the Activity. It has no LayoutParams if it's not added to any parent.
Use

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200) // I'm not sure about constructor arguments.
testCircleButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Use different LayoutParams if your root layout is different(FrameLayout etc).